# Str function doesn't seem to convert an integer

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am iterating through a list of data,  trying to leave an equal and big enough gap for the data. Some of the data is an int, so len() doesn't play nicely with integers, I added the str function but it isn't converting it.

```
        for data in self.data:
            print(data)
            for d in data:
                if len(str(d))>len(self.gap):
                    self.gap = len(str(d))
```

the error I have is:

```
if len(str(d))>len(self.gap):
```

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `self.gap` is an integer.

If you are doing this for for example column alignment or any other reason to later convert them to string, read [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead.

Comment: self .gap is just a string of spaces. The if statement is the psudocode I haven't written yet I thought it'd give context